# R: Predictions from a list of coxph objects on newdata

Tags: r, dplyr, prediction, purrr

I am building a series of Cox regression models, and getting predictions from those models on new data. I am able to get the expected number of events in some cases, but not others.

For example, if the formula in the coxph call is written out, then the predictions are calculated. But, if the the formula is stored in an object and that object called, I get an error.  I also cannot get the predictions if I try to create them within a dplyr piped mutate function (for the function I am writing, this would be the most ideal place to get the predictions to work properly).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Daniel

```
require(survival)
require(tidyverse)
n = 15

# creating tibble of tibbles.
results = 
  tibble(id = 1:n) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(
    # creating tibble to evaluate model on
    tbl0 = tibble(time = runif(n), x = runif(n)),
    # creating tibble to build model on
    tbl =  tibble(time = runif(n), x = runif(n))
  ) %>%
  ungroup 

#it works when the formula is added the the coxph function already written out
  map2(results$tbl, results$tbl0, ~ predict(coxph( Surv(time) ~ x, data = .x), newdata = .y, type = "expected"))

#but if the formula is previously defined, I get an error
  f = as.formula(Surv(time) ~ x)
  map2(results$tbl, results$tbl0, ~ predict(coxph( f, data = .x), newdata = .y, type = "expected"))

# I also get an error when I try to include in a dplyr pipe with mutate
  results %>%
    mutate(
     pred = map2(tbl, tbl0, ~ predict(coxph( f, data = .x), newdata = .y, type = "expected"))
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out (with the help of a friend).  If you define the formula as a string, and within the function call coerce it to a formula everything runs smoothly.  I am not sure why it works, but it does!

```
#define the formula as a string, and call it in the function with as.formula(.)
  f = "Surv(time) ~ x"
  map2(results$tbl, results$tbl0, ~ predict(coxph( as.formula(f), data = .x), newdata = .y, type = "expected"))

#also works in a dplyr pipe with mutate
  results %>%
    mutate(
     pred = map2(tbl, tbl0, ~ predict(coxph( as.formula(f), data = .x), newdata = .y, type = "expected"))
    )
```